# Как сложить числа в массиве объектов после итерации

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив с объектами у которых есть ключ price, мне нужно после итерации сложить между собой числа 12.99 и 14.99. P.S Итерация в моем случае мне нужна

```
const arr = [{price: 12.99}, {price: 14.99}];
arr.map(item => {
 //сложить по ключу price 12.99 + 14.99
});
```

Comment: Если на выходе нужно получить одно значение, то это делается так: arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price, 0)

Comment: Используйте reduce вместо map

Comment: @Anynomius , да уже делал через reduce, но вот была проблема в том что если в arr хранится не два объекта с ключом price а больше то складывались все price, а мне нужно к примеру сложить только два объекта

Comment: два каких? отобраных по какому-то критерию?

Comment: @entithat то есть если бы у меня к примеру был бы массив [{price: 12.99}, {price: 14.99} {price: 5.99}, {price: 18.99}, {price: 10.99}] то мне нужно было бы сложить только 12.99 + 14.99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`массив.shift()` удаляет первый элемент массива и возвращает его же. Вот и взять его, добавить к следующему элементу:

```js
const arr = [{price: 12.99}, {price: 14.99}, {price: 'Не трогать'}];

if (arr[1]) arr[1].price += arr.shift().price;

console.log(arr);
```

Если нужно так приклеить несколько элементов в определенном месте, используйте **[arr.splice(индекс, сколькоЭлементовУдалить [, чтоДобавитьНаИхМесто])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** -> возвращает новый массив из удаленных элементов.

```js
const arr = [{price: 5},   {price: 1}, {price: 1}, {price: 1},   {price: 10}];

let new_obj = { price: 0 };
let removed = arr.splice(1, 3, new_obj);

new_obj.price = removed.reduce((sum, e) => sum + e.price, 0);

console.log(arr);
```